# bash script to find out largest git tag name

Tags: bash, git

Say below command list all git tags, how to modify it to get the largest tag?

```
git tag

Current output is:

    V1.0.0
    V1.0.1
    V1.0.2
    ...
    V1.0.23
```

I expect the output is V1.0.23 for this example

Comment: `sort -V | tail -1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have Git sort them for you, by version, descending, and pick just the first one:

```bash
git tag --list --sort='-version:refname' | head -n1
```

Or pipe the tags to a sort that knows version sort (such as GNU sort):

```bash
git tag | sort -rV | head -n1
```